# How to make a nested query in Realm?

Tags: realm

I have two realms:

```
public class ChatRealm extends RealmObject {
    private String id;
    private RealmList<UserRealm> users;
}

public class UserRealm extends RealmObject {
    private String id;
    private String username;
}
```

I have an User id and I want to know which chats he is participating in. I have check the Realm documentation and couldn't find how to do this type of queries.

How can I get the results I want using a Realm query?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about link query in documentation?
There is an example:

```
RealmResults<ChatRealm> contacts = realm.where(ChatRealm.class).equalTo("users.id", "some id").findAll();
```

Comment: I think this should only work with one-to-one relationship. Not sure if link queries works with one-to-many relationships like this.. Let's wait for OP then..

Comment: Christian from Realm here. Link queries also work on one-to-many relations. Right now it it returns a match if any of the items in the list match.