# Android: using Realm to make a nested query?

Tags: android, sql, realm, realm-migration, realm-list

I have a list of Teachers that each contain a list of Student objects. Each Student contains a list of schoolbooks that he has to bring each day. It looks like this:

```
Teacher { 
String teacherName;
RealmList<Student> students = new RealmList<>(); 
}

Student { 
String studentName;
RealmList<SchoolDay> schooldays = new RealmList<>(); 
}

SchoolDay { 
String day;
RealmList<RealmString> schoolbooks; 
}
```

(RealmString is simply primitive `String` wrapped as a `RealmObject`)

I want to extract the list of schoolbooks for a certain student on a certain day - several students might have the same schoolbooks, but I'm only interested in the books for one particular student on one particular day (for example, Sunday). A student might be in the classes of several teachers, but I'm only interested in the result for one of them as the weekly booklist will be different for each one. Sample query data might be:

```
teacher : steven

student : austin

day     : sunday
```

This is where I get stuck - how do I subquery this? To get the teacher that I'm interested in:

```
RealmResults<Teacher> = realm.where(Teacher.class).equalTo("teacherName",  "steven").findAll();
```

However, I then have to run a subquery on the teacher and a subquery on the student - or better yet, run all of them in the same query somehow. What I want to get as my final result is just the string representing the schoolbooks for that one particular student. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try like that :

```
realm.where(Teacher.class)
.equalTo("teacherName",teachername)
.equalTo("students.studentName",studentname)
.equalTo("students.schooldays.day",day).findAll();
```

After all you have Teacher object(s) and you can get variables in one query :

```
RealmResults<Teacher> teachers= your query above;
    for(Teacher teacher:teachers){
       //remember still you can have multiple students for given teacher
       for(Student student:teacher.getStudents()){
           for(Schoolday schoolday:student.getSchooldays()){
             schoolday.schoolbooks bla bla bla...
           }
       }
    }
```

Why we using for loop : because `findAll()` method can return multiple results, if you want single Teacher object use `findFirst()`

This will return you Teachers of given **teachername** attribute that contains/includes students with given student name : `studentname` and those students have schooldays with given: **day** name.

I think the last explaination is quite a bit hard to understand, now I explain it with examples:

1. In first query you are getting Teachers with name= "Yasin".
       Assume that after this query you got 5 Teachers with name "Yasin".
2. Then in second query you are searching this 5 Yasin teachers; if their one of students name is "Jon". Assume that you have 3 Yasin teachers after that query.
3. Then in the last query you searching of that 3 "Yasin" teachers; if their one of students school day is "Sunday".

You can take a look at this question : [how-to-make-a-nested-query-in-realm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30616140/how-to-make-a-nested-query-in-realm)

Also this question is good for referencing ; it was helpful for me: [realm-android-nested-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35276531/realm-android-nested-query)

Comment: Thanks, however this method will only return the teacher object and I want to get back the String containing the schoolbooks. Is there no way of selecting the schoolbooks string directly from Realm?

Comment: @Jon when you get teacher you can get schoolbooks of his in one query. If you don't know how to do I can edit my answer. I am saying this because `findAll()` methods can return multiple teachers with given name and you can use for loop

Comment: Do you mean in one more realm query? Yes, I would appreciate it - many thanks.

Comment: @Jon I've edited my answer please take a look at it and if still you have questions let me hear them.

Comment: So what you're saying is that realm doesn't allow you to get anything other than the top-level object in the hierarchy and that everything underneath the top object has to be manually parsed?

Comment: @Jon i didn't used Realm before like that. And actually I didn't understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you explain me more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121465/discussion-between-jon-and-yasin-kacmaz).

Answer (score 4):

I would propose an easier option.

You can make use of [inverse relationships:](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#inverse-relationships)

The models will look like:

```
Teacher { 
    String teacherName;
    RealmList<Student> students = new RealmList<>(); 
}

Student { 
    String studentName;
    RealmList<SchoolDay> schooldays = new RealmList<>(); 

    @LinkingObjects("students")
    final RealmResults<Teacher> teacher = null;
}

SchoolDay { 
    String day;
    RealmList<SchoolBook> schoolbooks; 

    @LinkingObjects("schooldays")
    final RealmResults<Student> student = null;
}

SchoolBook { 
    String bookName;

    @LinkingObjects("schoolbooks")
    final RealmResults<SchoolDay> day = null;
}
```

And the query will be as simple as:

```
RealmResults<SchoolBook> = realm
    .where(SchoolBook.class)
    .equalTo("day.student.studentName", "austin")
    .findAll();
```